# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter.Update keeps database a step behind

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Okay, first of all, this problem is quite hard to describe. **I'm sorry if you don't understand my explanations.**

When I change values in a DataSet through a DataGridView and call SQLiteDataAdapter.Update() for the first time, it doesn't update the database. The database file doesn't even change "Last modified" time. However, after updating the DataSet and calling it again, it finally updates database...with the values it should updated in the first time.

If there were added/removed rows, it works fine. This only happens when values only get updated.

Now, if you didn't understand, here is a picture:
http://funkyimg.com/viewer.php?img=/2/1416/716/285481problem.png

Here is my code:

> ```
> using (SQLiteDataAdapter Adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + DataTable.TableName, Model.Connection))
>             {
>                 SQLiteCommandBuilder Builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(Adapter);
>                 Builder.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;
>                 Adapter.UpdateCommand = Builder.GetUpdateCommand();
>                 Adapter.InsertCommand = Builder.GetInsertCommand();
>                 Adapter.DeleteCommand = Builder.GetDeleteCommand();
>                 Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = true;
>                 Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
>                 Adapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;
>                 Adapter.Update(Model.Set, DataTable.TableName);
>             }
> ```